# MBProgressHUD naming convention clarification

Tags: ios, memory-management, mbprogresshud

I came across a very nice API [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), however when I was reading the documentation in the header [MBProgressHUD.h](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/MBProgressHUD.h) I got confused since the doc says that `- (id)initWithWindow:(UIWindow *)window;` is a **convenience constructor**.

According to Apple docs regarding [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), convenience constructors should not be prefixed with any of the following: *init*, *alloc*, *copy*.

Can anyone clarifies whether I'm missing something here?

```c
/*** A convenience constructor that initializes the HUD with the window's bounds.  
* Calls the designated constructor with  
* window.bounds as the parameter.  
* @param window The window instance that will provide the bounds for the HUD.  
* Should probably be the same instance as  
* the HUD's superview (i.e., the window that the HUD will be added to).  
*/  
- (id)initWithWindow:(UIWindow *)window;
```

Comment: You should have added a bug report. :) Fixed now. https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/commit/4ba6e7f524577c84e15edfaf035382e994c3bfe7

Comment: woops, I will do that next time round :) Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the comment. The convenience constructors return autoreleased objects, but this `- (id)initWithWindow:(UIWindow *)window;` does not. Thus, the name of the constructor is fine, but the comment should be updated.

edit:
I always found the MBProgressHUD a bit complicated to my taste until i came across [this nice replacement](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) on github.

Comment: Thanks @mja for the clarification and also for the alternative progressHUD link. I gave it a look and yes it seems simple enough. However I want to point out that MBProgressHUD has one very good feature; with just one line you can display the HUD while running a @selector() and stopping as it finishes.